# AJAX'y image pop-ups in Plone 4

Tags: plone

Pipbox says it's "Plone 4 compatible way to do AJAX pop-ups in Plone 3".

http://plone.org/products/pipbox

Then, what's the proper way of doing jQuery Tools image pop-ups in Plone 4?

- Scan HTML for images using selector
- Install click handler
- On click open the image in pop-up, using one of predefined sizes from plone.app.imaging

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All pipbox really does is load plone.app.jquerytools support in Plone 3. In Plone 4, plone.app.jquerytools is built in.

plone.app.jquerytools loads jQuery Tools and some Plone-specific support for easy AJAX popups. That support allows you to associate AJAX popups with jQuery-selectable page components. See [the PYPI page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.jquerytools/1.4b1#overlay-helpers) for full documentation.

A quick example: let's say that you want to set up lightbox-style popups for images in the content area using the preview-scale supplied by plone.app.imaging. JS to do this is:

```javascript
jQuery( function($) {
  $('img.image-right, img.image-left, img.image-inline')
    .prepOverlay({
      subtype: 'image',
      urlmatch: '/image_.+$',
      urlreplace: '/image_preview'
      });
});
```

You would load this code by registering a javascript resource as a skin or browser layer, then add it to the portal_javascripts js resources.

The code:

1. Sets up a function to load when the page is ready, with "jQuery" aliased to "$";
2. Selects all image items in the page that use the styles used by the visual editor;
3. Calls the prepOverlay routine (from plone.app.jquerytools) to associate them with overlays;
4. Specifies that the overlays will be images, which means that size information may be determined from the loaded image;
5. Does a little regular expression matching and replacing to pick up the image URL and convert it to a preview.

Comment: Ok. I was little confused because Pipbox provides portal_properties settings to add these, but in fact it is even simpler to do them with pure JS.